# insertar input time en Mysql usando php

Tags: php, mysql

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente formulario, me genera error cuando intento insertar el input time con los datos del formulario, que puedo estar haciendo mal

```
<form action="workingtime.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="L" name="name_l">
<input type="time" name="from_l" value="<?php  echo date("H:i", strtotime('01:00 AM'));?>" class="form-control">
</form>
```

*** "working_time.php"

```
if (!empty($_POST['from_l'])) {
    $from_l = $_POST['from_l'];
    $name_l = $_POST['name_l'];

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql_l = "UPDATE working_time SET from='$from_l' WHERE name='$name_l'";
    if($db->exec($sql_l)){
echo 'Ok';
    }else{
echo 'Error';
    };

}
```

**como esta compuesta la tabla** 
[image: Tabla WOrking Time]

Este es el error

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'from='01:00' WHERE name='L'' at line 1 in
>   /var/www/html/your6/controllers/workingtime.php:23\nStack trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/your6/controllers/workingtime.php(23): PDO->exec('UPDATE
>   working_...' –

Comment: Y cuál es el error que te da?

Comment: Que tipo de dato usas para almacenar dicho valor?

Comment: Este es el error -- > PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from='01:00' WHERE name='L'' at line 1 in /var/www/html/your6/controllers/workingtime.php:23\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/your6/controllers/workingtime.php(23): PDO->exec('UPDATE working_...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que de hecho dice

> access violation......

se genera pues en tu query usas la palabra reservada *from* la cual está reservada por el motor para indicar la tabla a la cual se le aplicará dicha operación.

Soluciones

1. Coloca entre backticks **``** o comillas simples invertidas dicha palabra, para indicarle que lo lea como `string` y no como una palabra reservada del sistema.
2. Modifica el nombre de dicha columna para evitar estos errores y colócale un nombre descriptivo

**Referencias**

- [Lista de palabras reservadas en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)